# How should I check that a given argument is a datetime.date object?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm currently using an `assert` statement with `isinstance`. Because `datetime` is a subclass of `date`, I also need to check that it isn't an instance of `datetime`. Surely there's a better way?

```
from datetime import date, datetime

def some_func(arg):
    assert isinstance(arg, date) and not isinstance(arg, datetime),\
        'arg must be a datetime.date object'
    # ...
```

Comment: I think the idea of polymorphism is that instances of subclasses are type-compatible with instances of the base class. As such, it only makes sense that `datetime` objects are instances of `date`, so I don't think there's a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't understand your motivation for rejecting instances of subclasses (given that by definition they support all the behavior the superclass supports!), but if that's really what you insist on doing, then:

```
if type(arg) is not datetime.date:
    raise TypeError('arg must be a datetime.date, not a %s' % type(arg))
```

Don't use `assert` except for sanity check during development (it gets turned to a no-op when you run with `python -o`), and don't raise the wrong kind of exception (such as, an `AssertionError` when a `TypeError` is clearly what you mean here).

Using `isinstance` and then excluding one specific subclass is not a sound way to get a rigidly specified exact type with subclasses excluded: after all, the user might perfectly well subclass `datetime.date` and add whatever it is you're so keep to avoid by rejecting instances of `datetime.datetime` specifically!-)

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't normally think about doing this type of checking, but as I posted on the other response: I'm writing a graph plotting function for day-over-day data, and if you pass in a datetime object, the information it spits is gibberish (but may look correct at first glance). If an exception was raised somewhere during the execution of my function I wouldn't bother, but it confused me when I accidentally passed in a `datetime` and I wouldn't want to do that to a user of my library.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for pointing out my misuse of `AssertionError`. A `TypeError` is indeed what I meant.

Comment: It didn't work for me on  2.7:  "if type(thing) is not datetime.date: raise TypeError"

Comment: Works fine for me in 2.7 if `arg` is any of: 23, datetime.datetime.now(), 'foo'. @JoshUsre, please give the specific case in which "it didn't work for you"!

Comment: `In [66]: type(oc.created_date)`
`Out[66]: datetime.date`

`In [67]: type(oc.created_date) is datetime.date`
`Out[67]: False`

Comment: @DavidM.Brown, looks like you have two independent copies of module datetime (e.g via a reload or something). How/when is `oc.created_date` generated? *That* is "the specific case" needed for debugging (probably best expounded at length in another Question, rather than in cramped comments).

Answer (score 5):

If your problem is that the graph goes wonky because it is using fractions of a day, you can test for that in other ways e.g. `hasattr(arg, 'hour')` distinguishes between a `datetime` instance and a `date` instance.

Answer (score 4):

The Python way is not to check it, just go ahead and let your code do what it needs to do, and if the object doesn't have a required method or something, the code will fail with an exception at the point where that method will be called. This is called [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) and it is part of what makes Python so flexible.

Now, if you really can't accept a `datetime.datetime` object... well, why can't you? A `datetime` can do anything a `date` can do, so I can't imagine what reason you'd have for disallowing a `datetime`, or indeed any subclass of `date`.

If you *really really* have a good reason for doing this (I guess maybe as a debugging thing, but even then, I don't get it...):

```
assert type(arg) == datetime.date
```

Comment: I'm writing a graph plotting function for day-over-day data, and if you pass in a `datetime` object, the information it spits is gibberish (but may look correct at first glance). For this reason, I'd rather raise an exception than spit out data that could leave a user of my library rather baffled and scratching their head for a while. If an exception was raised somewhere I wouldn't bother doing this, but since it might confuse someone who accidentally uses `datetime`, I'd rather raise an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your edit; that example helped! I don't know why I didn't think to use `type()`.